# Is there a visual studio add-in that can check if CSS classes/id's are not in use across the solution?

Tags: css, visual-studio, add-in

Just as the title states.

If not, any good web services you've used to cleanup bloated stylesheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about Visual Studio but there are [some FireFox plugins](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&expIds=17259,24815,26515&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=firefox+unused+css&cp=11&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=f&aqi=g4g-o1&aql=&oq=firefox+unu&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=6f32b8af52b7e0b8).

Answer (score 0):

[Dust-Me Selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/) is a Firefox plugin that will find unused styles on a given web page. I don't know of any Visual Studio plugins that will do this.

Comment: I have it... good plugin. I was hoping there was a visual studio add-in that could do it solution wide before publishing. Plus, dust me requires a sitemap that has every possible page of the site within it. (which would be best of course),. Thanks.